# Changing the filterId of ApexPages.StandardSetController is not changing the records returned

Tags: apex, visualforce, list-view

I'm writing a visualforce page with custom controller that shows a list of contact records. I want to add list view filter on the records.
I have added the filter successfully using ApexPages.StandardSetController class. I have debugged the filterId to see if it is changing, and it is changing. But in all the cases the records returned by getRecords() method is same.
Below is the code:

```
public class ListViewFilterController {
//private List<Contact> contactList;
private ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc;
private List<SelectOption> options;
private String selected;

public ListViewFilterController() {
    this.ssc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController([SELECT Firstname, Lastname FROM Contact]);
    //this.contactList = (List<Contact>)ssc.getRecords();
    //System.debug(ssc.getFilterId());
    this.options = ssc.getListViewOptions();
    this.selected = ssc.getFilterId();
}

public List<Contact> getContactList() {
    //System.debug('Contact Size: ' + this.ssc.getResultSize());
    //System.debug('FilterId in ContactList: ' + this.ssc.getFilterId());
    return (List<Contact>)this.ssc.getRecords();
}

public ApexPages.StandardSetController getSsc() {
    //System.debug('StandardSetController filterId: ' + this.ssc.getFilterId());
    return this.ssc;
}

public List<SelectOption> getOptions() {
    //System.debug('Getting List OPtions');
    return this.options;
}

public String getSelected() {
    System.debug('The currect filterId: ' + this.selected);
    return this.selected;
}
/*
public void setContactList(List<Contact> contactList) {
    this.contactList = contactList;
}
*/
public void setSsc(ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc) {
    this.ssc = ssc;
}

public void setOptions(List<SelectOption> options) {
    this.options = options;
}

public void setSelected(String selected) {
    //System.debug('Update filterId to ' + selected);
    //System.debug('Currect FilterId of SSC: ' + this.ssc.getFilterId());
    this.selected = selected;
    this.ssc.setFilterId(selected);
    //System.debug('Updated FilterId OF SSc: ' + this.ssc.getFilterId());
}
```

}

Here is the visualforce code:

```
<apex:page controller="ListViewFilterController">
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!selected}">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"></apex:selectOptions>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="recordList" />
        </apex:selectList>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contactList}" var="c" id="recordList" >
            <apex:column value="{!c.Firstname}" />
            <apex:column value="{!c.Lastname}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

</apex:page>

I have read almost all the posts on stackexchange and salesforce forum, but I could not understand why changes are not being reflected while changing the filterId. I'm new to salesforce. So, please explain what happens internally to ApexPages.StandardSetController instance when we change the filterId and how can I solve the above problem.

Thanks in advance!